# Not wanted extra space between two sections - background image reasons in Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new at the Bootstrap. Before I was writing a grid by myself, but now, I thougt, that I should learn new thing.

I'm making a basic site with background image in one of the containers. I don't know why, I have an extra padding added. I was trying with `background-size`: `contain` and `cover`, but it is not the effect that I want.

And I need that `padding-bottom` to stretch the container. The mathematical operation is the height of the image split with with and multiply with percetage. In my own grid it was working like a fairy tale.

Now I'm missing something. Any ideas?

This is jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/LukMona/qwqck9bp/2/

CSS:

```
.bg-img {
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url("https://github.com/LukMona/Doctors_Search_Basic/blob/master/images/header_background.jpg?raw=true");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: 100% auto;
  -moz-background-size: 100% auto;
  -o-background-size: 100% auto;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  padding-bottom: (1210/2808)*100%;
}
.main-top-header {
  position: absolute;
  width: 90%;
  margin-top: 2%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  margin-right: 5%;
}
.main-top-header-left {
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  width: 25%;
  margin: 0;
}
.logo {
  margin: 0;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 2.5rem;
  margin: 0;
}
.main-top-header-right {
  position: relative;
  float: right;
  width: 75%;
}
ul {
  text-align: right;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 5%;
  font-size: 2rem;
}
a:link {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  color: blue;
}
.main-search {
  background-color: grey;
  width: 80%;
  margin-left: 10%;
  margin-right: 10%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 2%;
  padding-bottom: 5%;
  border-radius: 3%;
  position: relative;
  ;
  top: 10rem;
}
.searching {
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.find {
  width: 80%;
  background-color: grey;
}
span:first-child {
  padding: 2%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}
.search {
  float: left;
}
input {
  height: 3rem;
  width: 75%;
  padding-left: 2%;
}
button {
  width: 20%;
  height: 3rem;
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
}
nav {
  background-color: grey;
  height: 200px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<header class="container-fluid bg-img">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 main-header">

      <!-- TOP HEADER -->
      <div class="main-top-header">

        <div class="main-top-header-left">
          <div class="logo">
            <h1>
                      Logo
                    </h1>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="main-top-header-right">
          <div class="menu">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">one</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">two</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">three</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#">four</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- END OF TOP HEADER -->

      <div class="main-search">
        <div class="searching">
          <span>type something</span>
          <br>
          <input class="search" type="text" name="search" placeholder="typing">
          <button class="search">
            <span>find</span>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<nav class="row">
  <div>
    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12">

    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Please explain once more. Where is extra padding? What do you mean? https://i.gyazo.com/a6d72610fe201c78de89e3f12b20674d.png

Comment: @GlebKemarsky sorry for late answer - I've edited my code, now jsfiddle is all right. There is an extra space between header and nav section.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you call the header, the nav section and an extra space. Can you circle by red? https://i.gyazo.com/19fac6b1899638fc107e623c03a14d28.png

Answer (score 0):

Remove `.main-top-header { position: absolute; }` and `.main-top-header-left { position: relative; }` that will work

Comment: sorry, it's not it :( any other ideas?